# Передача массивов в строке get запроса Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

Не могу понять как описать контроллер под такой запрос.
Приходит GET запрос такого вида

```
/endPoint?status[]=1&status[]=3&status[]=7&status[]=9&status[]=4
```

как это представить?

вот так не отрабатывает

```
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) List<String> status
```

и так тоже

```
@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) String[] status
```

Answer (score 0):

Не верно был передан запрос

`&status=1&status=3` вот так нужно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, чтобы имя параметра в запрос соответствовало имени в контроллере. Т.е. если передаете `?status[]=1&status[]=2`, то в контроллере указывайте со скобками (список или массив - не важно):

```
@RequestParam(value="status[]") List<String> status
```

Или нужно поменять название параметра в запросе `?status=1&status=3`.